# Redaction using itext 5 for a scanned pdf

Tags: itext

I was trying to redact data from scanned PDF using Itext 5 but somehow it's not working out for me. I was only able to create redaction but not able to apply it. I tried with their given examples but it only works until creating redaction

```
String fileName = "scanned.pdf";
String  dest = "output_scannedPdf.pdf";


PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC + fileName);
int page = 1;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(500, 50, 200, 300);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(DEST + dest));
PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(stamper.getWriter(), rect);

annotation.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("Redact"));
annotation.setTitle("My author");
annotation.put(new PdfName("Subj"), new PdfName("Redact"));
float[] fillColor = { 0, 0, 0 };
annotation.put(new PdfName("IC"), new PdfArray(fillColor));
float[] fillColorRed = { 1, 0, 0 };
annotation.put(new PdfName("OC"), new PdfArray(fillColorRed));
stamper.addAnnotation(annotation, page);

// manipulatePdf(dest, dest1);

PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(stamper);
cleaner.cleanUp();
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception in `extractLocationsFromRedactAnnots()` method `PdfName annotSubtype = annotDict.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE);`

Comment: *"but it only works until creating redaction"* - and what does it do then instead? What are the symptoms? Any exception? If there is, please supply the stack trace.

Comment: Please share the code for the better help.@naidu

Comment: getting null pointer exception in extractLocationsFromRedactAnnots() method   PdfName annotSubtype = annotDict.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE);

Comment: Can you also share the pdf in question for reproducing the issue?